# Determine the loaded path for DLLs

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, dll

I wish to have my application in the following structure.

```
Exe
 |
 |----- DLL\DLL.dll, DLL\common.dll 
 |
 |----- DLL2\DLL2.dll, DLL2\common.dll
```

My EXE will load the DLLs through

```
LoadLibraryEx(_T("DLL\\DLL.dll"), 0, 0);
LoadLibraryEx(_T("DLL2\\DLL2.dll"), 0, 0);
```

`DLL.dll` and `DLL2.dll` project will link against `common.dll` through lib file. There will be 2 different versions of `common.dll` though.

However, during execution, `Exe` expected me to place `common.dll` same directory as `Exe`, but not same directory as `DLL` and `DLL2`. Is there any way I can resolve this, by able to have the above directory structure. Yet, still use lib to link against `DLL/DLL2` with `common`.

Comment: Check out Chris Becke's answer here for another possibility: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396754/can-different-versions-of-dll-be-loaded-in-same-application/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. **You want to load two different DLLs with the same name (common.dll) into the same process.**

   That seems like a bad idea to me. Is it really necessary? Could one of them be renamed?
2. **Ensuring the DLLs you load can find other DLLs which aren't in the search path.**

   (If you were not dynamically loading DLL.dll and DLL2.dll then I'm not sure what the would be. Luckily, I see you are. :))

   If you are dynamically loading DLL.dll and DLL2.dll (that is, using LoadLibrary at runtime instead of linking to their .lib files at build time), then you can call [SetDllDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686203%28VS.85%29.aspx) beforehand to explicitly add the DLL or DLL2 directories to the search path. You would want to only have one directory in the path at once to ensure the right common.dll was loaded.

   Note that it is good practice, unless it breaks a poorly-written component, to call SetDllDirectory("") at the start of your program to remove the current-working-directory (*not* the program's directory, don't worry) from the DLL search path. This mitigates security issues where your code can be tricked into loading DLLs. But also note that if you reset the search path by calling SetDllDirectory(NULL) then you need to call SetDllDirectory("") again afterwards.

So you'd have code like this:

```
SetDllDirectory(NULL); // Reset.
SetDllDirectory(""); // Plug "binary planting" security hole. `
SetDllDirectory("C:\MyExePath\DLL");
LoadLibrary("C:\MyExePath\DLL\DLL.dll");

SetDllDirectory(NULL); // Reset.
SetDllDirectory(""); // Plug "binary planting" security hole.
SetDllDirectory("C:\MyExePath\DLL2");
LoadLibrary("C:\MyExePath\DLL2\DLL2.dll");

SetDllDirectory(NULL); // Reset.
SetDllDirectory(""); // Plug "binary planting" security hole.
```

(Untested so apologies for any mistakes or missing arguments. Should give you the idea, though.)

(You should calculate the C:\MyExePath at runtime. Hard-coding it would be bad, obviously.)

(I am assuming that DLL.dll and DLL2.dll load their common.dll implicitly. If they are loading common.dll via a LoadLibrary call then the problem is even easier: Just make them calculate their own paths and then pass LoadLibrary the full path to common.dll.)

Beware: SetDllDirectory affects your entire process. If your process has multiple threads you should ensure the SetDllDirectory calls are isolated from each other as well as anything else that may trigger a LoadLibrary call. e.g. Load the libraries at startup before you spawn any other thread, if possible.

Comment: Yes. Your solution works quite fine. This enable me to load DLLs from different directory. Just that, there will be problem when loading DLL with same name.

Comment: May I know, where there is "Plug "binary planting" security hole"?

Comment: @Yan See here: http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/news/2010/08/new-windows-dll-security-flaw-everything-old-is-new-again.ars -- For more info, see here: http://www.binaryplanting.com and http://www.binaryplanting.com/guidelinesDevelopers.htm

Comment: @LeoDavidson I want to load two versions of the same dll with the same name. It's just for testing purposes, to ensure that results differ in a way I want them to differ. At this point, renaming would be too much work, so is there a way to do this?
1. Run the calculation with test.dll in folder1
2. Run the same calculation with test.dll in folder2

Answer (score 5):

It won't work. You can't link "DLL2\DLL2.dll" to "DLL2\common.dll". DLL2.dll will be linked against "DLL\common.dll". There will be a "common.dll" in memory when "DLL2.dll" is loaded, so the imports of DLL2.dll will be resolved against that DLL.

Note that suggestions such as `PATH` or `SetDllDirectory` do not work. They affect how `LoadLibrary` finds "common.dll", but `LoadLibrary("common.dll")` is called only once, for DLL\DLL.dll.

Comment: +1 (despite my own answer) as I suspect you are right about having two DLLs with the same name, if they are loaded that way. (The main part of my answer should/may still be useful for the other half of the problem, though.)

Comment: You are right. If the DLL\common.dll is being loaded, DLL2\common.dll will not be loaded. Do you think is there way I can resolve this?

Comment: Can you change the DLLs to use LoadLibrary (not implicit linkage) and specify the full path to their respective DLLs? AFAIK that should work even if you cannot rename the DLL. For example, there are lots of shell extension DLLs with the same (poorly chosen, generic) name loaded into Explorer. (Unless those things don't work?)

Comment: Example of what I just mentioned: http://www.pretentiousname.com/temp/twodllsonename.png

Comment: @Leo Davidson: shell extension DLL's are COM components; obviously Explorer.EXE isn't linked against them. The restriction is really in the imports section, not in `LoadLibrary`.

Comment: @MSalters: COM DLLs are loaded via LoadLibrary in the end. There's nothing special about them. I'm saying he shouldn't use the imports section at all and just use LoadLibrary with full path. i.e. Don't link to common.dll, load it at runtime.

Comment: @Leo Davidson: that's precisely the point. Nobody argues that `LoadLibrary` prevents you from loading two DLLs. That's why I point to the import table. That's the bit which is path-agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this will really be fun.

The basic thing here is, to load the DLLs from other paths, you either must specify the full path (when using LoadLibrary) or expand the PATH environment variable to include the other folders that contain your DLLs. See setenv for details on how to do that.

A simple solution is to provide the relative path to LoadLibrary. But is seems you are linking the DLLs and thus you can't apply this solution.

The problem is no matter what your project layout is the runtime linker will use the current working directory and the PATH variable. Since you seem to be linking the library there is no chance you can "fix" the PATH variable just after loading the first DLL and before the second DLL. The remaining solution is to rename the common DLL to something like common-1.dll and common-2.dll. This also has the benefit that you can actually put them all into the same directory.

(If you are using LoadLibrary in any case, then just fix the PATH var...)

Comment: for security reasons dotnet1-4 only allows to load libraries either from gac or from a path that is below the main-path.

    ie LoadLibraryEx(_T("..\\DLL.dll"), 0, 0);

is NOT allowed

Comment: It was never said that .Net was involved here. And native does not care.