# Can different versions of DLL be loaded in same application?

Tags: c++, dll, manifest, dllimport

My application uses one version of library (a.dll), I am using another DLL(b.dll) which in-turn uses older version of the same library (a.dll) that i use. I am building the application by embedding a manifest file. The DLL i use is also using a embedded manifest file. I am having both the versions of the library in my WinSXS folder. My application is not able to load the appropriate versions of DLLs.

Will having a separate manifest file (not embedding into DLL) help resolving the problem? What is the work around?

Comment: Use the profiling functionality of Dependency Walker to see which DLL's your application tries to load.  This might already point you to the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your situation is exactly the situation WinSxS is supposed to solve. It should be working.

Either: The manifest files are pointing to the same version, or one of the manifest files is not embedded properly, or

The shared assembly in WinSxS was installed with a configuration policy that automatically redirects requests for v1.0 to v1.1

---

Some clarifications are needed: App.exe and b.dll are implicitly linked against a.dll? Or do they load it via LoadLibrary.

If B.DLL loads A.DLL explicitly using LoadLibrary then you need to add ISOLATION_AWARE_ENABLED to your pre-processor definitions to ensure that LoadLibrary calls made by B.DLL look in the correct activation context. Otherwise they will be made in the context of the default activation context which was created by the EXE's manifest.

Comment: I'm not sure WinSxS helps here. WinSxS allows you to provide a manifest for the exe that ensures the process loads a particular version of a DLL. The problem here is different modules within the same process need different versions of the same DLL. AFAIK WinSxS offers no solution for that, though I'm no expert on WinSxS and may be wrong.

Comment: hmmm? App.exe, uses a manifest to reference sharedassembly.1.1\a.dll, and loads b.dll, which also contains a manifest that references sharedassembly.1.0\a.dll - This is 100% the scenario that 'application isolation' was designed to support.

Comment: That sounds like "module isolation" rather than "application isolation," but maybe I'm wrong. My quick check of the docs gave me the impression that WinSxS lets AppX.exe load 1.1\a.dll and AppB.exe load 1.0\a.dll, but not a single app loading multiple versions of the same DLL (which seems a recipe for disaster in general, though it could work with some DLLs).

Comment: @Christ, I might well be wrong. Although the documentation is far from explicit, I found this which does seem to back up what you're saying: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375197%28v=VS.85%29.aspx -- So +1 to your answer from me. I'll also mention it in the other question in case it's of use there.

Comment: The technology is in places completely misnamed. application isolation does in fact mean module isolation as applications can already load different versions of the same dll. "application isolation" and "application manifest files" allow dll's to declare dependencies on, and load different versions of, the same (named) dll by partitioning a process into 'activation contexts.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on what the duplicated DLLs do and if their versions are compatible. (e.g. Do they both access shared objects in memory? If so, there's a good chance something will blow up.)

It will also depend on how those two same-named DLLs are loaded. If it's anything other than an explicit LoadLibrary with a full path then things probably will not work. There's an ongoing discussion of this here: [Determine the loaded path for DLLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385806/determine-the-loaded-path-for-dlls)

In general, it might work if you're lucky. The fact it may go catastrophically wrong is a good reason to avoid the issue entirely, if you can. (In the worst case, you could host one of the modules in another process and proxy all the calls to it. Ideally, just be able to use the same DLL version in both modules.)