# Loading same DLL's with same depending DLL's from different folders

Tags: c++, dll

I would like to load the same DLL from different subfolders to compare there results, after for example some refactoring. The DLL I would like to load have some depending DLL's which are linked to it, so they are loaded implicitly.
To make the work easier and to keep overview of the DLL's I organise them in different sub-folders within the current working dir. So I have following structure:

```
CurrentWorkingDirectory
-> MyApp.exe
-> DllSubDir1
---> ManuallyLoaded.dll
---> DynamiclyLinked.dll
-> DllSubDir2
---> ManuallyLoaded.dll
---> DynamiclyLinked.dll
```

I managed to load the two different versions of ManuallyLoaded.dll by using `LoadLibraryExA` and the absolute path to the different DLL's. So I can see the two loaded ManuallyLoaded.dll instances in the debugger.

However, unfortunately the DynamiclyLinked.dll is loaded only once.

To compare all aspects of the ManuallyLoaded.dll after some refactoring, I also would like to load the potentially different versions of DynamiclyLinked.dll. Is there a way to force the application to load implicitly the same DLL from different folders? Or do I need to rename the potentially different version of DynamiclyLinked.dll?

Answer (score 0):

After some time spend in investigation and testing I finally found a possible solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5018526/11264951

In my case it was necessary to

1. add the depending manifest for DynamicLinked.dll to the ManuallyLoaded.dll. For example with such a pragma. But note to do this in one of the cpp files of the ManuallyLoaded.dll. Because if you do it in one of the h file, the exe will complane about the missing manifest. I assume, during compile time, everything what in added by pragma, is added to the exe.

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/manifestdependency:\"acme.common'processorArchitecture='*' version='1.0.0.0' type='win32'\"")
```

2. build in the manifest in the ManuallyLoaded.dll by setting the corresponding settings in the properties.