# SetDllDirectory, reset (mandatory)?

Tags: c++, dll

we have an application using SetDllDirectory

```
exe
 |
 |--DLLDirectory\Any1.dll
 |--DLLDirectory\Any2.dll
```

Any1.dll, call SetDllDirectory("DLLDirectory") before LoadLibrary
----- at this point, should we call SetDllDirectory("")
Any2.dll, call SetDllDirectory("DLLDirectory") before LoadLibrary
----> at this point, should we call SetDllDirectory("")

application load the Any#.dll

```
SetDllDirectory("DllDirectory")
LoadLibrary(Any1.dll)
// SetDllDirectory("") ?
SetDllDirectory("DllDirectory")
LoadLibrary(Any2.dll)
// SetDllDirectory("") ?
```

My doubts, is it neccessary/mandatory to reset dll directory after LoadLibrary? If it is mandatory to reset, how if some one else e.g.: the Any1.dll call GetDllDirectory

[SetDllDirectory function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686203(v=vs.85).aspx)
[Determine the loaded path for DLLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385806/determine-the-loaded-path-for-dlls)
I have refer to the post above, but still need some one here to advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**: No, it's not mandatory.

**Long answer**: Calling `SetDllDirectory` with an empty string `""` only removes the **current directory** from the default DLL search order. If you want to restore the default search order, then you need to pass `NULL` as the parameter. The reason why you want to do any of that is for **security** reasons. Basically, it's risky performing run-time dynamic linking, because you don't know the current state of the **Search Order**. That's why it's good practice to **reset** the Search Order state. The decision to reset the Search Order state after each `LoadLibrary` call depends on whether or not you trust that library.

Please read the following articles for more details:

- [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Dynamic-Link Library Security](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff919712(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Your better off passing complete path to LoadLibrary and never calling SetDllDirectory.

While it's unlikely, another code pulled in and running on other thread can change this on you.

Comment: e.g.: my application is in D:\App\Any.exe , my code call SetDllDirectory(DLLDirectory), so LoadLibrary(Any.dll) will go into D:\App\DLLDirectory, do you mean LoadLibrary("D:\App\DLLDirectory\Any.dll") is more appropriate? without calling SetDllDirectory?